# Suggestions on big data and the limitations of SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, bigdata, database

I started working with Databases and I am still novice.

I am facing a problem related to Sales and Visits in (initially) 10 thousand establishments. I am working with Microsoft SQL at the moment.

For each of these establishments, I want to plot graphs of sales and visits with filters by year, month, week, day, product, region, establishment, and any other possible combination of these filters. I also need to correlate this data with data from other establishments from the same region, all else being equal (other filters).

These 2 tables will be fed from a database that usually has 1 million transactions per year per establishment. This data will be simplified and inserted in the target database.

As a starting point, I though about the following schema for each tables:

```
int EstablishmentId
int RegionId
int Year
int Month
int Week
int Day
int Hour
decimal Value
```

Considering the amount of data, I think a SQL server wouldn't be able to handle it by default. I am not an expert in databases, so I went after a solution and I found out about partitions, partitioning by year, month, week, day, product, region and establishment (and certain combinations, maybe), but apparently SQL 2016 can handle up to 15000 partitions, therefore it wouldn't be possible.

I am here to ask for opinions, so I can look after possible solutions and study them. I am sure you are more knowledgeable than me, therefore you can point me in the right direction by showing me a better approach.

One last information: I will have more tables. I am just presenting the most simple one. These tables will have pre-processed data, but in high quantities, with filter possibilites.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you even know what big data is? here's a hint: it doesn't mean you work with lots of data.

Comment: You can run that db on your phone...

Comment: your  SQL Server could handle the  expected volume with adequately sized hardware. Read for sql server handling  billions of row http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129223/total-billions-of-rows-and-daily-millions-of-row-insert-what-database-system-su

Answer (score 1):

The kind of volume of data that SQL Server can handle really depends on what kind of hardware you are running on.  What you are talking about would be well under theoretical thresholds for SQL Server running on high end hardware.

I think what you are wanting to do with partitions could likely be done with appropriate indexes on your table ... I don't think you are really understanding the functional use of partitions.

A 'big data' solution (I do not know if you are meaning to use that term in the technical sense or if you are just talking about a relative volume of records) could fit what you are trying to do, but understand that would not be something a novice would just slap in and leverage.  What you can do in your situation would really depend on the backgrounds and expertise of the developers working on the project.

Based on the little information you have provided, if I was going to suggest a direction for you to pursue understanding I would point you towards [SQL Server Analysis Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231701.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Do not fall into the habit of assuming that a number which seems large for a human would be large for a computer. It is very easy to test such theories using a simple script like the one below.

One row in your example table would take 32 bytes of data + row overhead + indexes.
If we approximate it to be 100 bytes per row, with 1M rows we would get 100MB. This is excluding data compression.

100MB is tiny data, not big data.

SQL Server is capable of handling much much more than this and I would consider it to be suitable considering the analytics you wish to do on the data.

A COLUMN STORE INDEX would be a perfect fit for this type of table and those kind of queries.

In this example i generate 5M rows and puts a simple column store index on top.
All of my test-queries at the bottom finishes in 1 to 3 seconds on my laptop. Considering I have no additional indexes and absolutely no tuning of hardware or partitions, I think that is more than enough performance.

My test-table is occupying about 24MB after running this script.

```
if object_id('table1') is not null drop table table1;

create table table1(
    EstablishmentId    int ,
    RegionId           int ,
    Year               int ,
    Month              int ,
    Week               int ,
    Day                int ,
    Hour               int ,
    Value           decimal 
    )
;

insert into table1(
    EstablishmentId ,
    RegionId        ,
    Year            ,
    Month           ,
    Week            ,
    Day             ,
    Hour            ,
    Value)

select n % 100, n % 10, n % 20, n % 12, n % 52, n % 256, n % 24, 55 * n
from (
    SELECT TOP (5000000) 
        n = CONVERT(INT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])) 
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
) data
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCIX  
    ON table1;


exec sp_spaceused 'table1'

select sum(value) from table1 where year between 50 and 5000
select sum(value), year from table1 group by year
select sum(value), year, week from table1 where EstablishmentId = 55 group by year, week
```

Tested on SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition.

**Edit**:

If you wish to use this challenge as reason to play with "big data tools" then go ahead. It will be a great learning experience.